# 0 as approximate eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: matrices, analysis, inequality

i got a problem that i cant solve. And i would be grateful for some help.
Given the matrix $ X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &  &  \\
-1 & 0 & \ddots &  \\
 & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
 &  & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $ im supposed to show that there exists for every $c > 0$ a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd,  such that $\Vert Ax \Vert_\infty < c \Vert x \Vert_\infty$. I really tried to find such a vector but i couldnt quite come up with a vector that satisfies this inequality for a $c > 0$. It would be nice, if anyone could give me some tips on this topic or a choice for $x$ to start with. 
Have a nice day!

Comment: With $n$ fixed? Not very plausible, is it... If the question is to show this when $n\to\infty$ then a natural candidate for such a vector emerges, no?

Comment: If n is odd the matrix is not well defined as you define it in blocks of $\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}$ which are 2x2. Also what is $A$, is it supposed to be $X$?

Comment: @mathreadler No, this is standard notation for tridiagonal matrices. In MATLAB notation you could say e=ones(n,1); A=spdiags([e -e],[1 -1],n,n)

Comment: alright, my misinterpretation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By noting $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) $, you have $Ax = (x_2, x_3 - x_1, x_4 - x_2 , ..., x_{n}- x_{n-2}, x_{n-1})$.

So if you take $\forall i \in [1,\frac{n-1}{2}], x_{2i} = 0 $ and $ x_{2i+1} = 1 $, you have $Ax = 0 $ and $x \neq 0$ ...

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment, it was applicable with $n$ even. Indeed when $n$ is odd $0$ is actually an eigenvalue and an eigenvector is as you wrote.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is correctly asked, since this vector can be used to prove $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall c >0, ||Ax||<c||x|| $, which implies $ \forall c >0, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n, ||Ax||<c||x|| $.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first column, it will only have one non-zero entry. Then you look at the last column. Same there. They will be connected through a set of equations with pair-wise overlapping -1 and 1, and no other row will be non-zero there. Therefore any linear combination you can build is bound to have two or more non-zeros. So no matter which row operations we could use the "end points" will be linearly dependent on some other point.

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
\bf -1&0&\bf 1&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&\bf -1&0&\bf 1&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&\bf -1&0&\bf 1\\
0&0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Matrix with bold elements in the sub-space we consider. If we look carefully we see 3 equations (rows) and 4 unknowns (columns). More unknowns than equations : will not be solveable so it must have at least one zero eigen value associated with it. It is then easy to show by induction if we add two more at a time it will be one new of each equation and unknown.